# How to solve this error: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given?

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

I'm trying to setup different user types and their respective permissions in my `AppServiceProvider.php` in my project, and I get the error 
`explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`

Nowhere in my code do I have an `explode()` at least that I can see. Before adding the `Inertia::share(function(){})` there was no such error.

This is my code:

```
public function register()
{

    Inertia::version(function () {
        return md5_file(public_path('mix-manifest.json'));
    });

    Inertia::share(function () {
       $auth = null;
       if (Auth::user()) {
           $perms = [];
           $user = Auth::user();

           if ($user->isSuperAdmin() || $user->isAdmin()) {
               $perms = [
                   [
                       'url' => '/',
                       'icon' => 'fa fa-home',
                       'name' => 'Dashboard'
                   ],
                   [
                       //rest of permissions
                   ],
               ];
           }
           if ($user->isUser()) {
               $perms = [
                   [
                       'url' => '/',
                       'icon' => 'fa fa-home',
                       'name' => 'Dashboard'
                   ],
                   [
                       //rest of permissions
                   ],
               ];
           }

           $auth = [
               'id' => Auth::user()->id,
               'name' => Auth::user()->name,
               'card' => Auth::user()->card,
               'scard' => Auth::user()->scard,
               'user_type_id' => Auth::user()->user_type_id,
               'email' => Auth::user()->email,
               'perms' => $perms
           ];
       }
       return [
           'app' => [
               'name' => Config::get('app.name'),
           ],
           'auth' => [
               'user' => $auth,
           ],
           'flash' => [
               'success' => Session::get('success'),
           ],
           'errors' => Session::get('errors') ? Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->getMessages() : (object)[],
    ]
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Where i'm getting the error it doesn't specify where the error is, just what it is, it signals the last line of the code I presented as where the error is, but all that's there is the closing parenthesis and brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing nothing of Inertia, it seems you are misusing the `Inertia::share` function. In their [docs](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data), I see 3 examples. The first two have parameter 1 being a string (eg. `'auth.user'` or `'app.name'`), and the last has parameter 1 being an associative array, so each element still has a unique string key.

In your code, you are passing a closure as the first parameter. I believe that you can fix it by simply adding a name as the first parameter:

```
Inertia::share('auth.user', function () {
    $auth = null;
    if (Auth::user()) {
        $perms = [];
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($user->isSuperAdmin() || $user->isAdmin()) {
            $perms = [
                [
                    'url' => '/',
                    'icon' => 'fa fa-home',
                    'name' => 'Dashboard'
                ],
                [
                    //rest of permissions
                ],
            ];
        }
        if ($user->isUser()) {
            $perms = [
                [
                    'url' => '/',
                    'icon' => 'fa fa-home',
                    'name' => 'Dashboard'
                ],
                [
                    //rest of permissions
                ],
            ];
        }

        $auth = [
            'id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'card' => Auth::user()->card,
            'scard' => Auth::user()->scard,
            'user_type_id' => Auth::user()->user_type_id,
            'email' => Auth::user()->email,
            'perms' => $perms
        ];
    }
    return [
        'app' => [
            'name' => Config::get('app.name'),
        ],
        'auth' => [
            'user' => $auth,
        ],
        'flash' => [
            'success' => Session::get('success'),
        ],
        'errors' => Session::get('errors') ? Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->getMessages() : (object)[],
    ];
});
```